# Angular material select display under dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angular-material, ng-dialog

i'm having a weird issue and don't know the way of solve it.

i have a dialog generated by `ngDialog` and inside this dialog i have the `md-select` but it doesn't display properly. It show under the dialog doing the select unreadable or clickeable

is there a way to use CSS to fix this??

[image: md-select]

**EDIT**

this is the `modal-cerrar-nota.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="ngdialog-message" md-theme="docs-dark">
    <md-toolbar class="md-warn">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h3 class="modal-title" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                ¿Deseas finalizar esta nota de credito?
            </h3>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content flex>
        <md-content class="md-padding" flex>
            <div layout="column" class="md-padding">
                <p flex style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Una vez finalizada esta acción no podras deshacerla.</p>
                <form name="cerrarNota" 
                      ng-controller="ClienteController"
                      data-ng-init="listaClientes()">
                    <md-input-container class="md-block md-icon" flex>
                        <label>Seleccione un cliente</label>
                        <md-icon class="material-icons">&#xE7EF;</md-icon>
                        <md-select ng-model="cli"
                                   ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.idCliente'}"
                                   required name="cliente">                                            
                            <md-option ng-value="cliente" 
                                       ng-repeat="cliente in clientes">{{cliente.nombreCliente}}</md-option>                                            
                        </md-select>
                    </md-input-container>
                    <div flex style="text-align: center;">
                        <button type="button"
                                ng-click=""
                                class="btn btn-success">Devolver</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </md-content>
    </md-content>
    <md-content flex class="md-padding">
        <button class="btn btn-md btn-danger pull-right"
                ng-click="closeThisDialog('')">Cerrar</button>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

and here is my function to trigger it.

```
$scope.cerrarNotaCredito = function () {
    ngDialog.open({
        template: 'views/nota_credito/modal-cerrar-nota.html',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-sm ngdialog-theme-custom',
        showClose: false,
        controller: 'ModalController',
        closeByDocument: false,
        closeByEscape: false
    });
};
```

please tell me if you need also the CSS of the ngDialog `className`

Comment: How do we run your code ?

Comment: my bad, wait a min pls i'll add that

Comment: @Rayon done. i've added it.

Comment: Working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/suunyz3e/258/

Comment: uhm, i think that i haven't explained well jeje.. the dialog (modal) is triggered from a buttom on my main template. when it show as a dialog(modal) the select is displayed under the dialog.

Comment: you can provide z-index value to get it displayed above dialog...I have faced this type of problem earlier, I solved it by using custom bootstrap-select or you can refer to https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#styling, it has more options and it worked fine with our use case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a month i've tried once to solve this problem with a successful result.

i just add `z-index` as Ajay said.

In the css of the dialog `className: 'ngdialog-theme-sm ngdialog-theme-custom',`

more specific on the custom css `ngdialog-theme-sm`

```
.ngdialog.ngdialog-theme-sm {
z-index: 80;
padding-bottom: 50px;
padding-top: 50px;
-webkit-perspective: 1300px;
-ms-perspective: 1300px;
perspective: 1300px;
-webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 150px;
-ms-perspective-origin: 50% 150px;
perspective-origin: 50% 150px;
}
```

That's all and working pretty fine. Hope this help to someone with the same problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, the solution didn't work for me :(